# using an apply function with ggplot2 to create bar plots for more than one variable in a data.frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

Is there a way to use an apply function in R in order to create barplots with `ggplot2`?

Say, we have a dataframe containing only factor variables out of which one is boolean. In my case I have a dateframe with +40 variables. Can one plot all the variables against the boolean one with a single line of code?

```
  data("diamonds")
factors <- sapply(diamonds, function(x) is.factor(x))
factors_only <- diamonds[,factors]
factors_only$binary <- sample(c(1, 0), length(factors_only), replace=TRUE)
factors_only$binary <- as.factor(factors_only$binary)
```

But I want to create barplots like this one:

```
qplot(factors_only$color, data=factors_only, geom="bar", fill=factors_only$binary)
```

This does not work:

```
  sapply(factors_only,function(x) qplot(x, data=factors_only, geom="bar", fill=binary))
```

Please advise

Comment: you could reshape your data, and use `facet_` : `m = reshape2::melt(factors_only, id="binary") ; 
ggplot(m, aes(value, fill=binary)) +
  geom_bar() + facet_grid(. ~ variable, scale="free_x")` (but you will need to reorder your bars using `factor` on `m$value`: along these lines perhaps: `aes(factor(value, levels=unlist(lapply(factors_only, levels))), fill=binary)`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to run through the variable names and then use `get` to pull up the current variable.

```
temp <- lapply(names(factors_only),
               function(x) qplot(get(x), data=factors_only, geom="bar", fill=binary, xlab=x))
```

To print a list item,

```
print(temp[[1]])
```

will produce

[image]

A nice feature of running through the variable names is that you can use these to dynamically name the labels in the figure.