# Why does x axis label show df[,1] and not the column names?

Tags: r, ggplot2, sapply

I am trying to get histograms of all columns of a data frame **isNumVal** using sapply. Codes below:

```
sapply(isNumVal, plotHist)

plotHist <- function(df){
          df <- tbl_df(df)

            print(
              ggplot(df, aes(x = df[1])) + geom_histogram() 
            )

          }
```

[image: ggplot histograms]

The x axis label in all the plots is showing df[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwASF.jpg).

How do i get it show the name of the columns?

Comment: Hi useR. its not working. ggplot is substituting "value" in place of "df[,1] in all plots with your code.

Comment: Because `df[1]` is what you assigned to x, not whatever the column is called

Comment: It's also well documented that using the name of the data frame inside `aes` will often introduce errors and scoping issues. You can use a tidyeval approach, or there are other SO questions that will help programmatically create ggplots

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using an apply function with ggplot2 to create bar plots for more than one variable in a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41895513/using-an-apply-function-with-ggplot2-to-create-bar-plots-for-more-than-one-varia)

Comment: Add `+ xlab(lab name )` after your `geom_histogram( )` call as in http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/labs.html. Also see the example to properly write the `(aes())` function as pointed out by @camille

Answer (score 0):

There are many other ways, here is one. Try to pass dataframe and the column name to your function, and use `aes_string`:

```
plotHist <- function(myDf, myCol){
  ggplot(myDf, aes_string(x = myCol)) + geom_histogram()
}

lapply(colnames(isNumVal), function(i) plotHist(isNumVal, i))
```

Comment: thank you zx. It works.

Can you point me to some reading to understand why my original code doesn't work.

Comment: @RaviShankarHela Sorry, don't understand your question?

Comment: What is wrong with the code below:

    sapply(isNumVal, plotHist)

    plotHist <- function(df){
          df <- tbl_df(df)

            print(
              ggplot(df, aes(x = df[1])) + geom_histogram() 
            )

          }

Comment: @RaviShankarHela as explained by other in the comments, you are losing the names of your dataframe when subsetting. In `functoin(df)`, the `df` is a unnamed vector, that you are converting to a dataframe, which you again subsetting using `df[1]`.

Comment: Got it. Thank you all!